# node.js proxy a request to third party server return bad request

Tags: node.js, proxy

am using the request module to proxy a request to a third party serve, i followed the documention but it seems am not building the request well so i get this error in the response `BadRequest`.
here is the code:

```
auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

    request.post( 
        {
            url: url, 
            headers : {
            "Authorization" : auth,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        } ,
            qs: params
    }, function(err, response, body){
        var resBody = qs.parse(body);
        console.log('thats the body ',resBody);
});
```

note the end point is an `https`

Comment: Are you can show err?

Comment: there is no error making the request, but the response from the endPoint is 
{ '{\n  "success": false,\n  "errorMessage": "Request entity exp
ected but not supplied",\n  "errorCode": "BadRequest"\n}': '' }